# Can't download Skyrim Texture Pack from Steam

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I'm having trouble downloading the [Skyrim High Resolution Texture Pack](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/High_Resolution_Texture_Pack) from Steam, when I click on the download link, I get the following error screen.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows if this is a common bug on Steam or is the Texture Pack no longer available?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to click on the download link. Go over your Games Library, find The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim -> Right click -> Select properties and then navigate to the DLC tab.

You'll see the "Skyrim High Resolution Texture Pack" in the list, simply tick the empty box and then close the window. The game should start to update right away.

Comment: Probably too late, but I actually don't advise doing this via steam.  This is because the texture becomes permanently attached to your game and you will always have to download the extra 3 gigs before you can play.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you download your mods from another source: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim.

I found much better resources on this site than on Steam. Plus the mods and other things are much easier to manage, due to the Nexus Mod Manager. As well I'm sure that the "Skyrim High Resolution Texture Pack" is available there too.